# Bundle does not exist or it is not enabled after deleting a bundle Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

Hey all please i need help with symfony 3 bundles after i deleted a bundle called 'HomeBundle' from AppKernel.php and routing.yml i get an error msg in my cmd

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]   Bundle
>   "HomeBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to
>   add it in the registerBundles() method    of your AppKernel.php file?
>   in @HomeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml (which is being imported
>   from "C:\wamp64\   www\projects\pipcke\app/config\config.yml"). Make
>   sure the "HomeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" bundle is cor
>   rectly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the
>   bundle is registered, make sure the bundle pat   h
>   "@HomeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" is not empty.
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]   Bundle "HomeBundle" does not exist or
>   it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles()
>   method    of your AppKernel.php file?

Can anyone help thanks a lot

Comment: Error messages often provide clues: app/config/config.yml

Comment: Please use formatting to make your question more readable (code, quote etc)

Comment: most likely you have "HomeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" imported in app/config/config.yml

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: i can't clear the cache it shows me the same error message when im trying to

Comment: @ymoreau i don't know how to formatte my question sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete HomeBundle folder from /src and clear cache

Comment: Nope Nope Nope.  Read the question and look at the error message.

Comment: i did deleted HomeBundle folder from src and nothing new about clearing cache i can t it shows me the same error when trying to clear the cache

Comment: Cerad i read question. It says " i deleted a bundle called 'HomeBundle' from AppKernel.php". i thought he was not deleted from /src.

Comment: Škắŉ Dridi can you share config.yml and service.yml files? Did you removed bundle namespace path from composer.json under "psr-4" key?

Comment: @Cavid how can i share those files plz?

Comment: Thanks guys i ve found the solution it looks like i ve fotgot to delete - { resource: "@HomeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" } from the config.yml. I did followed the symfony documentation and it s worked ,i appreciate for trying to solve my problem

Comment: Congurlation! Next time you can share file contents via pastebin.com :)